# calling pyautogui.locateOnScreen to pyautogui.Center not working

Tags: python, pyautogui

the locateOnScreen function being passed to the Center function gives me this error and i dont know why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wilme\Desktop\Programming\pyton dedikation\små projekt\getcoord.py", line 8, in <module>
    iploc = pyautogui.center(ip)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\wilme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 649, in center
    return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
                 ~~~~~~^^^
```

```
import pyautogui
import time

screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()

ip = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("ip.png")
iploc = pyautogui.center(ip)

q = pyautogui.confirm('vad vill du göra?', buttons=['skapa ip', 'skicka meddelande till jesper'])

if q == 'skapa ip':
    pyautogui.moveTo(27,1062)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.write('ngrok')
    pyautogui.moveTo(107,466)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.write('ngrok tcp -region eu 25565')
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(iploc)
```

what's wrong?

.............................................